# Using Java to create PDF graphs based on Excel formulas

Tags: java, excel, pdf, graph, processing

Yeah the titles confusing, but heres what im trying to do

1. Obtain 6 .txt files in Java (more or less depending on what i need)
2. Put them into a excel document cells and allow a graph to sort the data (without bringing up the excel window, if possible)
3. Create a single-page PDF using the graph created in the excel document
4. Open PDF Viewer and show the PDF.

I have no idea how to do any of this. Im good in basic Java so i can do #1 for the .txt file processing and how to insert data into cells, but once i have to create the graph I get lost.

Dont be afraid to post anything if you dont know every single step, I just want to take it step by step.

Note: The graph be a horizontal line graph, there will be (num of text documents) # of "Series" and every series has about 10 pieces of data

Comment: Have you seen http://processing.org ? A lot of people mistag processing... It's a very cool Java framework for graphics stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the Apache POI project, an API for reading and writing Microsoft documents. [Here's](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) a link to its support for Excel. I don't know if it will help you with the graph, though.

Then you could take a look at the [Apache PDFBox project](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Comment: I'm already using Apache to write to XML, didn't know it had a PDF component aswell. The hard part seems to be getting the graph from excel..